# Mysql table doesn't exist error, references wrong table name

Tags: mysql

I have a table that I can query fine...

```
SELECT * FROM search.books LIMIT 1;
```

Returns a value correct.

However, when I try and update the table...

```
UPDATE search.books SET title='sometitle' WHERE id='12345'
```

It returns

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'search._books_new' doesn't exist
```

I'm not sure why it's referencing '_books_new' and not the one specified ? It's possible the table was copied previously as it's a dev server.

Engine is MyISAM

I have tried a

```
check table search.books
```

Also have restarted mysqld, but no difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like there is a [trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/triggers.html) on the `search.books` table that is attempting to insert into the non-existent table, `search._books_new`

This query will display a list of triggers in the database:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS
```